# Optimizing relative errors with GAMs

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am currently building a model GAM model to describe house prices. The dataset is a collection of roughly 200K house sales prices $\{p_{i}\}$ in a particular geographic region along with a range of variables $\{x,y,var_{1},var_{2} \}$ describing the house such as its geographic location, condition etc.. My strategy, which seems to be widely used in the literature on this subject, is to predict the prices using a hedonic regression model of the form:

$$
P = s(x,y) + s(var_{1}) + s(var_{2}) + … 
$$

My question is about whether the gam-routine (as implemented in the mgcv-package) has the ability to optimize different types of error measures. I am not an expert on the subject, but I would assume that the standard optimization procedure in GAM is roughly equivalent to the minimization of a least squares loss function of the form

$$ 
L_{1} = \sum_{i}(P(x_{i}, y_{i}, var_{1,i}, var_{2,i}, ..) - p_{i})^2
$$

In some applications one is however often more interested in performing well on the relative error scale, i.e. where the relative mean-squared-error is minimized:

$$ 
L_{2} = \sum_{i}\frac{(P(x_{i}, y_{i}, var_{1,i}, var_{2,i}, ..) - p_{i})}{p_{i}}^2
$$
Does this option in exist in the mgcv package? Or are there any data-transformations or other tricks that would achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do in `mgcv` by specifying weights for the observations. This is the `weights` argument in the `gam` function.

In your case, the weight corresponding to the $i$th observation is equal to $1/p_i$.